# How to get a list of files and sizes that count in my acount in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I'm using Dropbox in group. We have a lot of folders.

I want to see which files are occupying my space and how much space are occupying.

Now, I can enter folder by folder and click file by file to see the space.

Is there a better way? Can I get the list of all files of all folders in one list (only the files that are occupying my space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no. If you have your Dropbox files synced to a local drive, there are various tools for Windows, Linux, or Mac that tells you the folder/directory size and all contents underneath.

Comment: And if I have my files synchronized. Can I know which are my files and wich belongs to others?

Comment: That is a different question? Please post new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you open Dropbox Preferences, Sync, Select Folders, the list of folders shows sizes and if you drill down, the subfolders will also show size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I'm trying to get is how much of my space is occupying. Then if I have the space but not the owner of the file, I’m not getting the info I need.