# How to know which files are mine and which belong to anothers when sync folders with Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

To know how to know which files are ocuping my space in Dropbox @Sun suggested me to syncrhonize the folder in my computer. But I still not know how to know which files belong to me and which belongs to others.

My other question: [How to get a list of files and sizes that count in my acount in Dropbox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1185132/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-and-sizes-that-count-in-my-acount-in-dropbox)

Other ideas are welcomed!